# trivia game jquery can't display arrays after click

Tags: jquery, arrays

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
var questions = [{
    question: "Who is pokemons current mascot?",
    answers: ["clefairy", "pikachu", "greninja", "togepi"],
    correctAnswer: 2,
    score: 5,
    points: 5

}, {

    question: "At what level does nidorino evolve?",
    answers: ["16", "25", "30 with fire stone", "any level after 16 with moonstone"],
    correctAnswer: 4,
    score: 10,
    points: 10

}, {

    question: "In which region does the town of Humilau City belong too?",
    answers: ["johto", "kalos", "Unova", "Hoenn"],
    correctAnswer: 3,
    score: 15,
    points: 15

}, {

    question: "What was the total number of pokemon to date?",
    answers: ["951", "802", "730", "850"],
    correctAnswer: 2,
    score: 15,
    points: 15

}, {

    question: "Who's that pokemon?", // will be Swellow img
    answers: ["Swellow", "Pelipper", "Pidgeot", "Talonflame"],
    correctAnswer: 1,
    score: 5,
    points: 5

}, {

    question: "What year was pokemon released in japan?",
    answers: ["December 05, 1995", "Feburary 27, 1996", "March 15, 1996", "April 01, 1995"],
    correctAnswer: 2,
    score: 10,
    points: 10

}, {

    question: "What was the first created pokemon?",
    answers: ["", "Pikachu", "Rhydon", "Charizard"],
    correctAnswer: 3,
    score: 5,
    points: 5

}, {

    question: "What type is Spiritomb",
    answers: ["Ghost/ Dark", "Ghost/ psychic", "Dark/ Ghost", "Dark/ Poison"],
    correctAnswer: 1,
    score: 10,
    points: 10
}, {
question: "What hidden ability does sylveon have?",
    answers: ["Lightning Rod", "Pixilate", "Unnerve", "Vital Spirit"],
    correctAnswer: 2,
    score: 15,
    points: 15
}, {

    question: "IV stands for what?",
    answers: ["Intravenous", "Independant Values", "Individual Variation", "Individual Values"],
    correctAnswer: 4,
    score: 10,
    points: 10

   }];


var updatedQuestion = 0;
var correctAnswers = 0;

$("#q_a").hide();

$("#playGame").click(function () {

    $(".rules").hide();
    $("#q_a").show();
});


//Get first question
function firstQuestion() {
    for (let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
        $("#question").html(questions[i].question);

        //Loop through question array and create buttons for each answer
        // Clear button div of any newly created buttons
        $("#answers").empty();
        for (let i = 0; i < questions[i].answers.length; i++) {
            var a = $("<button>");

        }
    };
};

});
```

```html
<title>Trivia game </title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<main class="startingPage" id="startPage">

    <h1 class="pageTitle">CWD3500 - ASSIGNMENT 1 - Intro to js Libs W/ jQuery - TRIVIA X 10</h1>
    <hr> QUESTION #: <input id="qNumber"> POINTS: <input id="points"> SCORE #: <input id="score">
    <hr>

    <div id="q_a">
        <p id="questions">test </p>
        <ul id="anwsers">
        </ul>

        <button id="nextQuest">NEXT QUESTION</button>

    </div>

    <div class="rules">
        <p class="paragraph"> Welcome to Trivia X 10! You 'll be asked 10 questions, one at a time and be given n4 anwsers. Click on the choice to choose your answer the question. Each one is worth either 5, 10 or 15 points, depending on difficulty. Answer each on correctly for a score of 100 points. Click the button below to get started.</p>

        <button id="playGame" class="gamePlay">CLICK TO PLAY!</button>
    </div>


</main>
```

my arrays won't show once you click the start button and im a little lost on how to get them to display. I've tried a few things with no luck and my teacher likes to explain it the dumbest ways.
(sorry for this repeat won't let me post unless I add more description and I don't know what else to add to explain my code)

Answer (score 0):

Here I have made a  slight progress on your initial code and this loops through all your question and displays answers on click of next question.

Now rest you have to work on your logic to get the right selected answer and increment score value and display.

```js
 let questions = [
   {
                question: "Who is pokemons current mascot?",
                answers: ["clefairy", "pikachu", "greninja", "togepi"],
                correctAnswer: 2,
                score: 5,
                points: 5

      },
            {

                question: "At what level does nidorino evolve?",
                answers: ["16", "25", "30 with fire stone", "any level after 16 with moonstone"],
                correctAnswer: 4,
                score: 10,
                points: 10

      },
            {

                question: "In which region does the town of Humilau City belong too?",
                answers: ["johto", "kalos", "Unova", "Hoenn"],
                correctAnswer: 3,
                score: 15,
                points: 15

      },
            {

                question: "What was the total number of pokemon to date?",
                answers: ["951", "802", "730", "850"],
                correctAnswer: 2,
                score: 15,
                points: 15

      },
            {

                question: "Who's that pokemon?", // will be Swellow img
                answers: ["Swellow", "Pelipper", "Pidgeot", "Talonflame"],
                correctAnswer: 1,
                score: 5,
                points: 5

      },
            {

                question: "What year was pokemon released in japan?",
                answers: ["December 05, 1995", "Feburary 27, 1996", "March 15, 1996", "April 01, 1995"],
                correctAnswer: 2,
                score: 10,
                points: 10

      },
            {

                question: "What was the first created pokemon?",
                answers: ["", "Pikachu", "Rhydon", "Charizard"],
                correctAnswer: 3,
                score: 5,
                points: 5

      },
            {

                question: "What type is Spiritomb",
                answers: ["Ghost/ Dark", "Ghost/ psychic", "Dark/ Ghost", "Dark/ Poison"],
                correctAnswer: 1,
                score: 10,
                points: 10
      },
            {
                question: "What hidden ability does sylveon have?",
                answers: ["Lightning Rod", "Pixilate", "Unnerve", "Vital Spirit"],
                correctAnswer: 2,
                score: 15,
                points: 15
      },
            {

                question: "IV stands for what?",
                answers: ["Intravenous", "Independant Values", "Individual Variation", "Individual Values"],
                correctAnswer: 4,
                score: 10,
                points: 10

      }
        ];


  var updatedQuestion = 0;
  var correctAnswers = 0;

  $("#q_a").hide();

  $("#playGame").click(function () {

   $(".rules").hide();
   $("#q_a").show();
   firstQuestion();
  });

  $("#nextQuest").click(function () {

   firstQuestion();
  });




//Get first question
  function firstQuestion() {
   let curQnNumber = $('#qNumber').val();

   if(curQnNumber === ""){
    curQnNumber = 0;
   }

   if (curQnNumber == 10) {
    curQnNumber=0;
            }

            $("#questions").html(questions[curQnNumber].question);

    //Loop through question array and create buttons for each answer
    // Clear button div of any newly created buttons
            var ul = $("ul").empty();

            $.each(questions[curQnNumber].answers, function(prop, val){

     ul.append("<li>"+val+"</li>");
            });

   curQnNumber ++;
   $('#qNumber').val(curQnNumber);



  }
```

```html
<title>Trivia game </title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<main class="startingPage" id="startPage">

    <h1 class="pageTitle">CWD3500 - ASSIGNMENT 1 - Intro to js Libs W/ jQuery - TRIVIA X 10</h1>
    <hr> QUESTION #: <input id="qNumber"> POINTS: <input id="points"> SCORE #: <input id="score">
    <hr>

    <div id="q_a">
        <p id="questions"> </p>
        <ul id="anwsers">
        </ul>

        <button id="nextQuest">NEXT QUESTION</button>

    </div>

    <div class="rules">
        <p class="paragraph"> Welcome to Trivia X 10! You 'll be asked 10 questions, one at a time and be given n4 anwsers. Click on the choice to choose your answer the question. Each one is worth either 5, 10 or 15 points, depending on difficulty. Answer each on correctly for a score of 100 points. Click the button below to get started.</p>

        <button id="playGame" class="gamePlay">CLICK TO PLAY!</button>
    </div>


</main>
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code but now it won't run at all

Comment: You can see the result above. Hit the run code snippet button.